# Proper Method to Send Passport User to React Frontend

Tags: reactjs, passport.js

I have a NextJS app running with ExpressJS and PassportJS handling authentication and Redis storing and setting session cookies. I have my server-side passport authentication in place that sends a redirect on successful sign in, but I'm not sure the proper way for React and the front-end to retrieve the user information to be stored in a React Context after the page loads.

At the moment I don't find that information in the response data when the redirected page loads.
Do I have to somehow call the cookie that cookie for the information?

I have read solutions where axios makes a request on the front end to the endpoint rather than the form making the request to the server. Is this the only way?

The two approaches I have thought of are:

1. Rely on the server to accept the form submission, process and then passport redirect on success, however I don't see the `user` object present in the response object on the front-end.

> Front-End Component -> Form submission triggers server request ->
> Passport uses server-side redirect to success page -> store `user`
> object from response (currently not present)

2. Have the front-end make the api endpoint request with `axios` and return a json object.

> Front-End Component -> Login function triggers Route (Javascript
> request) -> stores `user` object from response -> redirects to success
> page

For **approach 1.** , here is my passport setup. Unfortunately not seeing the user object in the front-end and not sure if further has to be done to expose it.

**Passport.js:**
router.route('/signin/')
.post(passport.authenticate('local', {
successRedirect: '/app/profile',
failureRedirect: '/signin',
failureFlash: true
}))

**Form:**

```
<form method='post' action='/api/auth/signin'>
          <label>
            Username
            <input name='email' type='text' value={ email } onChange={ handleChange }/>
          </label>
          <label>
            Password
            <input name='password' type='text' value={ password } onChange={ handleChange } />
          </label>
          <button type='submit'>Sign in</button>
        </form>
```

For **approach 2.** , here is my passport setup. Since the front-end is creating the redirect, I return a json object to be stored.

router.route('/signin/')
.post(passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res, next) => {
console.log('/api/auth/signin/ : Triggered')
if (req.user){
res.json({
'authenticated': true,
'user_id': req.user.user_id,
'user_email': req.user.user_email
})
} else {
req.flash(message.auth.signin.error)
res.redirect('/signin/')
}
})

**Form with signIn function:**

```
const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Axios: signIn Triggered')
    axios.post(
      '/api/auth/signin/',
      { email, password } // you don't need to do email: email when key and value have same naming
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      const data = res.data;
      console.log("updateUserState")
      setUser(data)
      // you can't console log updated user data here, you should use a useEffect for that
    }).then(()=> {
      return window.location = '/app/profile/'
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

<form method='post' action='/api/auth/signin'>
          <label>
            Username
            <input name='email' type='text' value={ email } onChange={ handleChange }/>
          </label>
          <label>
            Password
            <input name='password' type='text' value={ password } onChange={ handleChange } />
          </label>
          <button type='submit' onClick={ signIn }>Sign in</button>
        </form>
```